# AngularJS How To Achieve Polymorphism / Dependency Injection (Best Practices)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop, polymorphism

This is a design pattern related question. I am not looking for an answer as to how to achieve the following, but rather the most widely accepted and way to achieve polymorphism in a service.

Suppose I had a service called getData. It needs to get some data, whether it be from a database, text file, or something hardcoded, and output it depending on what the settings are on the $scope in the controller. In this example below, suppose getData depends on the dataSource.

```
angular.module('testApp').controller('testController'), [$scope, myAwesomeService, function ($scope, myAwesomeService){
    $scope.dataSource = 'database'; //defines the source of the data

    $scope.getData = function() {
        //use myAwesomeService, get the data and output

        if($scope.dataSource ==='database') {
             return //do it the first way
        }            

        else if($scope.dataSource ==='text') {
             return //do it the second way
        } 

        else if($scope.dataSource ==='csvfile') {
             return //do it the third way
        } 
        else if($scope.dataSource ==='form') {
             return //do it the fourth way
        } 

    }

}]);
```

**Questions:**

1. **How would you achieve this generally in Javascript?** I am not sure about the best practices around achieving polymorphism in Javascript. I am used to using interfaces and dealing with the situation above by using dependency injection and passing in objects that adhere to the same interface, and call a common method, from the controller. Usually some other "class" would take care of selecting which object to instantiate and pass in, and therefore make the controller agnostic to concrete details as to "how it is done".
2. **How would one go about doing this in AngularJS?** 
   How would the pattern typically look? Can you give a "textbook" Angular way of achieving polymorphism?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to comment, but I realized it might be too long, so I'm going to post an answer.

If we are talking about `ES5`, polymorphism & inheritance can be achieved through prototyping.

For example:

```
function Auto(name,year){
   this.year=year;
   this.name=name;
}
Auto.prototype.showYear = function(){
   console.log(this.year);
}

function Car(name,year, model){
   Auto.call(this,name,year);
   this.model=model;
}
Car.prototype = Object.create(Auto.prototype);

//usage
var car = new Car('BMW',2015,'320d');
car.showYear(); // will output 2015
```

In `ES6` this can be done using `class` functions. You can read more about this,  [HERE](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ecmascript-6-power-tutorial-class-and-inheritance--cms-24117) ( it's gonna be very nice :D )

Below you'll find some code that might answer your question. Hope this is what you're looking for:

```
function BaseService(){
    this.dataSource='database';
}
BaseService.prototype.getData = function(){
    console.log('base: get data');
}


function TextService(){
    this.dataSource='text';
}
TextService.prototype  = new BaseService();
TextService.prototype.getData = function(){
    console.log('child text: get data');
}



function CsvService(){
    this.dataSource='csv';
}
CsvService.prototype  = new BaseService();
CsvService.prototype.getData = function(){
    console.log('child csv: get data');
}


function FormService(){
    this.dataSource='form';
}
FormService.prototype  = new BaseService();
FormService.prototype.getData = function(){
    console.log('child form: get data');
}



angular.module('myApp').factory('awesomeService', function(){

    var service={};

    service.getData = function(dataSource){

        var sourceService;

        if(dataSource='database'){
             sourceService= new BaseService();
        }

        if(dataSource=='text'){
            sourceService=new TextService();
        }

        if(dataSource=='csv'){
           sourceService = new CsvService();
        }

        if(dataSource=='form'){
          sourceService= new FormService();
        }

        return sourceService.getData(); // i'm going to assume getData returns a promise
   }

   return service;

});

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($scope,awesomeService){
  var myDataSource='database';

  $scope.getData = function(){
    awesomeService.getData(myDataSource).then(function(data){
         $scope.result=data;
    });
  }


});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In an Angular context, where would you put BaseService(), TextSerivce() etc.? With barely implementation details, it is already pretty long and hard to navigate. Is it common practice to put these services into their own angular services and inject BaseService, TextService etc. one by one into "awesomeService"?

Comment: It's not a written rule. It depends how you're building up your app's boilerplate. For example, I would put them in a 'dataService', which we'll be injected in other services;

angular.factory('dataService',function(){
    var service={};
 
    service.BaseService= function BaseService(){};
    service.BaseService.prototype.getData= function(){};
 
    service.TextService = function TextService(){} 
    service.TextService.prototype = new service.BaseService();
   
    return service;
});

Comment: If there is a possibility that they may be required outside of awesomeService (and they may, at least for testing), make them services. Since they are instantiated inside awesomeService, they should be `factory` services, not `service`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on factory services vs an angular service? Do you mean factory vs service in the angular context, or are you referring to something else? i.e. do you mean factory as in: angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', function(){});

Comment: In a service function will be invoked as a constructor, while in a factory, the main function will be invoked as a function. ( service returns the main function; factory returns main function's return object ) All my examples were written with .factory.

Comment: Ok. My previous comment/question wasn't clear.  I understand that in angular, factories return the "return" value in the anonymous function and in services return the anonymous function instantiated. I thought you were talking about factory as in "factory design pattern" commonly seen in many languages - never mind.